# What do you call an outside area that is in the center of a mansion?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've seen a few mansions designed so that the house is a sort of square where the center part of the square shaped mansion/house contains an outside area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the area is uncovered, open to the elements, it's a courtyard.

**Courtyard**

> An unroofed area that is completely or partially enclosed by walls or buildings, typically one forming part of a castle or large house.
>
> https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/courtyard

According to some definitions, *atrium* might be appropriate, but I agree with the following:

> The central uncovered area in a Roman domus was referred to as an *atrium*. Today, we generally use the term *courtyard* to refer to such an area, reserving the word *atrium* to describe a glass-covered courtyard.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courtyard

Comment: I agree, "atrium" in contemporary usage is a covered space, typically more than one story high, but not open to elements.

Answer (score 1):

This can be called an *atrium*.

> **atrium** *n*
>   1. Architecture A rectangular court, as:
>   a. A usually skylit central area, often containing plants, in some modern buildings, especially of a public or commercial nature.
>   b. The open area in the center of an ancient Roman house.

[From TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/atrium)

As you can see, this is derived from the layout of Roman houses, which featured just such a central open area.

Answer (score 1):

According to the OED an "atrium" is usually a covered area, though often with skylight of some kind. The closest to what @Robusto describes is sense 1d. *d. In a public building, a usually skylit central court rising through several storeys and surrounded by galleries at each level with rooms (shops, offices, etc.) opening off them. orig. U.S.*

A building which has an especially splendid interior court is [the Foreign Office in London](https://www.alamy.com/stock-image-the-architecture-of-the-covered-durbar-court-inside-the-foreign-and-160101365.html?pv=1&stamp=2&imageid=6C20DFF3-6121-43A3-B934-96161D38E42A&p=74166&n=0&orientation=0&pn=1&searchtype=0&IsFromSearch=1&srch=foo%3dbar%26st%3d0%26pn%3d1%26ps%3d100%26sortby%3d2%26resultview%3dsortbyPopular%26npgs%3d0%26qt%3din%2520the%2520quadrangle%2520at%2520the%2520foreign%2520office%2520in%2520london%26qt_raw%3din%2520the%2520quadrangle%2520at%2520the%2520foreign%2520office%2520in%2520london%26lic%3d3%26mr%3d0%26pr%3d0%26ot%3d0%26creative%3d%26ag%3d0%26hc%3d0%26pc%3d%26blackwhite%3d%26cutout%3d%26tbar%3d1%26et%3d0x000000000000000000000%26vp%3d0%26loc%3d0%26imgt%3d0%26dtfr%3d%26dtto%3d%26size%3d0xFF%26archive%3d1%26groupid%3d%26pseudoid%3d%26a%3d%26cdid%3d%26cdsrt%3d%26name%3d%26qn%3d%26apalib%3d%26apalic%3d%26lightbox%3d%26gname%3d%26gtype%3d%26xstx%3d0%26simid%3d%26saveQry%3d%26editorial%3d1%26nu%3d%26t%3d%26edoptin%3d%26customgeoip%3d%26cap%3d1%26cbstore%3d1%26vd%3d0%26lb%3d%26fi%3d2%26edrf%3d%26ispremium%3d1%26flip%3d0%26pl%3d), they call it "the Quadrangle".

The term *atrium* is used in Britain, but mostly for an enclosed space in a modern building. In an older building it would normally be called a ***Quadrangle***.

Answer (score 0):

The ancient Romans called this an [atrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atrium_(architecture)), and as far as I know this word is still used today, both for large buildings like hotels and shopping centers, as for smaller ones like houses:

> 2 a: a rectangular open patio around which a house is built

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/atrium))

A non-Latin term for this is simply 'indoor garden'.